# Using CasperJS to load dynamic, ajax-based content

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to load data off the playstation store using casperjs. Anytime I try to access the page I get the standard non-loaded html. Since the page builds itself off the javascript I'm not sure where to go from here. If I try to caputer it I just get a black square.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true,
    logLevel: "debug"});
var username = casper.cli.get('username');
var password = casper.cli.get('password');


casper.start('https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/login.jsp?request_locale=en_US', function() {
    casper.echo(casper.getPageContent());
    this.fill('form[id="signInForm"]', {'j_username': username, 'j_password': password}, true);
});

casper.thenOpen('https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/library/main', function() {
    links = document.querySelectorAll('li.firstCell.lastCell.cellGridVideoLibraryMain');    
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});


casper.run(function() { 
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried waiting with `casper.wait()`? Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: I've tried using wait(), my output as been this with verbose.

http://hastebin.com/xenexireme.sm